# Nested/inner classes in WCF?

Tags: wcf, class, nested

I would like to know if any problem exists after creating public nested/inner WCF classes (DataContracts). And if yes, what are theses problems.

(One of my colleague has seen some stuff on the Internet about such problems but they seem specific to some situation and we don't find a clear 'yes it will work' or 'no, nested classes don't work in WCF', therefore my guess is that they usually work.)

Comment: do you mean inherited classes?

Comment: No 'nested class' = 'inner class', http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_class

Answer (score 1):

Data Contracts form part of the public API your service exposes.  Despite being represented in code by plain CLR classes (albeit decorated with an attribute) - do not be fooled - they are really serialized on the wire in to strings for consumption by the client/server.  As such, from a service orientated view point, we must move away from the temptation to associated them to Object Orientated concepts.

Using Inheritance, Interface abstractions and nested classes all deal with OO concepts (polymorphism, abstraction and access), and even though some/all of these are technically possible in WCF (e.g. through the `KnownTypes` attribute) - just because you *can* do something - it doesn't mean you *should*.

I have no doubt there is some way to achieve the correct serialization behaviour to get WCF to recognize nested classes.  However, in doing so I suspect you are going against the grain of service orientation - and consequently not using the full power of your service orientated architecture.